# Quarkus swagger define responses

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, quarkus

Hi I would like to define own responses like possible error responses and also defining the default response incase I build my responses by my self like `return Response.status(OK).entity(new MyResponseObject())`
Something like this: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/
How can I do it?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are using swagger? Versions of libraries, for example. How and who parse your java objects to swagger documentation. Any other environment description also can be helpful.

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo I am using `io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi` as described on https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui. @Schema is working only for fields. @Tag for method and classes. Now I am looking for something like @Responses to describe the return value and also something to describe the security...

Comment: I actually found finally some documentation like this: https://ftp.fau.de/eclipse/microprofile/microprofile-open-api-1.0.1/microprofile-openapi-spec.pdf but most of the Annotations are not working as I expect. are there some examples around in the internet?

Comment: I found this very good example https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/05/11/building-an-api-using-quarkus-from-the-ground-up

Answer (score 1):

You can use `io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi` extension to add necessary annotations to your project. You can do it by adding dependency in Maven or Gradle.

For Gradle:

```
implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi")
```

For Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

By default SmallRye OpenAPI extension will check what type method return and it will use it in generated documentation. In your example it will be probably `Response` which will be converted just to empty JSON object.

### Single response

You can change your code to just return MyResponseObject object from method like this:

```java
  @GET
  @Path("/")
  public MyResponseObject someMethod() {
    return new MyResponseObject();
  }
```

In this case MyResponseObject will be automatically mapped to OpenAPI schema (all properties will be mapped to JSON object properties).

### Multiple responses

If you have more than one response e.g. response with object and response with error you can use annotations. SmallRye OpenAPI extension provides two annotations for this:

- `APIResponse` - for describing single response
- `APIResponses` - for describing multiple responses from single method

Both from `org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.responses` package.

Here is example with two different response codes:

```java
@APIResponses({
  @APIResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "Reservation confirmed"),
  @APIResponse(
    responseCode = "422",
    description = "Reservation can not be confirmed",
    content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON,
    schema = @Schema(implementation = GlobalError.class))
  )
})
public Response confirm(@PathParam("reservationId") long reservationId) {

    final var result = reservationService.confirm(reservationId);

    if (result.isOK()) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
    } else {
        return Response.status(422).entity(new GlobalError(result.getError())).build();
    }
}
```

I added two `APIResponse` annotations, one for each response code.

First APIResponse is for 204 (reservation confirmed) and nothing is returned that's why `content` and `schema` is not set for it.

Second APIResponse is for 422 (reservation can not be confirmed). In this annotation I set custom schema with my class, which is returned when user got 422 from API. You can also add description, which will added to your API documentation and displayed in Swagger.